# How can I create a custom Box application to move content directly into an MS-Access database?

Tags: sql-server, box-api, ms-access-2013

I would like to automate content delivery from box.com, directly into an MS-Access 2013 database app. Is it possible to do this? What ingredients are needed to accomplish this objective?

EDIT: A typical scenario is I have several law firms that handle personal injury cases. Their clients doctors, insurance companies, etc. put content (mainly PDF documents) into the box upload folders so that I can distribute them to the corresponding law firm that represents each client. I have an Access 2013/SQL-Server application which invoices each law firm for the service I provide, but I have to manually retrieve the documents from Box and forward to each law firm. Most of the Law firms have a case management application, also written with Access 2007. I would like to automate the retrieval and forwarding of the documents, along with my billing, to each law firm, using my Access app as an intermediary.

Comment: What does it mean to deliver content 'directly into' Access? What have you tried?

Comment: I need to automate the process of retrieving documents from [Box](http://box.com), a cloud dropbox, and storing them in an SQL-Server backend which has Access 2013 as its front-end.

Comment: This is a broad question. It would be helpful if you could edit your question to provide a typical workflow/scenario. Some things to keep in mind: What kind of documents are you working with? Do you need to support many users, or just one? Once you get the data from Box, do you know how to get it into SQL Server the way you want? Do you want this to be a scheduled task, or perhaps a web app? What language(s) are you comfortable developing/scripting with?

Comment: @JohnHoerr: Edited the question to include your requested scenario. Box provides a "Content API". I need to know what I have to do on my end (Access 2013/SQL) to retrieve the content from box. I also need to know how to forward the content to the appropiate destination (also Access, but 2007).

Comment: Am I correct that all of the documents you wish to work with exist in a Box account owned by you?

Comment: How do you know which document is for which law firm?  Is it by the filename, or does each law firm have a different upload folder that they use and collaborate you into?

Comment: @Peter different folder for each law firm.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information you provided in follow up questions, I understand the following to be true:

- All files of interest are contained in a Box account that you own.
- Each client's documents are in a separate folder.

Further, I'm going to stipulate that all of the Access/SQL Server-related file processing stuff is beyond the scope of this question, or is at least too broad to be addressed here in whole.

That said, you don't really need to use the Box API at all. Something like this might be easier:

1. [Download and install Box Sync](https://sites.box.com/sync4/), which will make your Box files easily available on your work computer.
2. From the Box web interface [choose the folders](https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/articles/201864048-How-To-Get-Started-with-Box-Sync) that you'd like to keep in sync.
3. Point your application to the client files in your Sync folder (e.g. `C:\Users\Frank\Box Sync\<Client>\Inbox`) for processing.
4. Forward the results via email or, better, write them back to the appropriate sync folder (`C:\Users\Frank\Box Sync\<Client>\Outbox`