# Can I create a custom MS-Access API to interface with other applications?

Tags: api, winapi, ms-access, odbc, integration

I was searching MSDN and several other Access forums for creating custom Access API's, but didn't see anything related. Is this possible? Can custom ODBC's be created for Access?

Comment: Is this question really just another more general re-statement of your other recent question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21806374/2144390)?

Comment: Not really, as it is oriented at finding out in general what capabilities does Access have for integrating with any applications, services, etc.

Comment: Surely you must have seen mention of the mechanisms for manipulating Access databases via ODBC and OLEDB, and for manipulating the Access application itself via Automation (`Access.Application` object). If you have some particular usage case in mind that is not covered by those options then please edit your question to elaborate. Similarly, please explain what you mean by a "custom ODBC ... for Access".

Comment: As to API capabilities with Access 2013, all I saw was [Choose the right API with Sharepoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060.aspx#Factors) and Win32.

Answer (score 2):

Hum, this is confusing since it not clear if you are talking about building interfaces with Access to OTHER systems, or are you talking about a building an Access interface that other programs can use?

ODBC is a "driver" provided by vendors to allow use of their SQL database systems and is something that you don't create in Access or FoxPro or in VB for that matter.  In fact I can't think of any data centric tool that would allow you to build your own ODBC driver. So this suggests some confusing here.

Extending Access.

Access for the last 20 years has had the ability to consume ActiveX (COM objects). So how one extends the ability of Access to communicate with other software and systems REMAINS the COM object choice. So for example one can use the MSXML library from Access (a COM object) and this allows one to consume web pages, and specify XML which opens the door to consuming web services. In fact I used MSXML to consume SharePoint web services for example.

However for consuming web services it is usually far better to build COM object with tools that can "already" consume web services. So one would use vb.net to create a COM object and THEN reference that COM object from MS Access (so just like we set a reference to outlook or word from Access, such COM objects are not limited to applications you purchase, but you are most free to create your own COM objects VB6, vb.net, c# or whatever).

Access does NOT have the ability to create ActiveX (com objects), but it certainly can consume ones you build in other languages.

NOTE:  I am using the term ActiveX and "COM object" interchangeability here – they are the same basic technology.

So if you ever used a desktop computer and any windows development tool, you find that "COM" objects are the choice and REMAIN the choice of how to extend Access, or even that of VB6. With managed code, things change somewhat, but vb.net is quite happy to create COM objects that work well with Access.

While Access cannot as a tool create ActiveX (com) objects, you can certainly compile Access code into an accDE and THEN reference that library code from the VBA tools->references. So you can extend and share VBA code in one library with "many" applications, but this is not a com object.

So just like in the past to extend desktop programs, you can build such extensions as COM objects and consume them from Access – this is the standard approach to extend Access to say consume web services.

Access cannot be used to build individual COM objects as UI parts, but the STANDARD means in our industry to create COM objects is able to be consumed by Access.

Last but not least:
Any application you build in Access CAN BE CONSUMED as a COM object by other applications. So while you cannot build individual COM objects, your WHOLE application is in fact a com object.

So if you build an Application in Access then using Excel, VB6, FoxPro, another Access application, C++, or C# or vb.net? They ALL CAN consume your application as a com object by simply creating an instance of Access and your application.

So any development tool that supports "com" can consume your application as a com object.  So any standard development tool, article or system for the last 20 years can consume your Access application as a COM object.

So while Access cannot create individual COM objects, the resulting Access applications are in fact a legal com objects that ANY application that supports COM can create an instance of your application.  This means  your code and VBA subruties etc. are callable from the host application that created the instance of your application. In theory any VBA code exposed as "public code" are thus able to be called from that other program.

So the "interfaces" available to Access remain the SAME as the near 20 year history of MOST desktop programs running on windows – that interface is COM.

So you have 20 years of history and 20 years of examples on the internet to have fun with - any example that shows how to create and consume a com object should work for your access application.

Comment: Been a long time since I've heard from you. Please send me your contact email about something else. As to my question here, the ability of Access to integrate/communicate with other apps through an API, aside from ODBC and OLEDB, as not every other app out there has these! An example is [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806374/how-can-i-create-a-custom-box-api-to-move-content-directly-into-an-ms-access-dat). What do I use on the Access 2013/SQL-Server end to retrieve and store content from this dropbox?

Comment: You simply will extend Access by using COM to consume that web service. Why not just sync the folder local and then use standard DIR and file commands that exist in VBA and then no web service calls are required? Drop box for some strange reason does NOT have a WSDL web service exposed. However while no web service is exposed they do expose features via HTTP. So you can easy write your own "get" and "put:" statements from Access (just use the MSXML library as it supports get/puts). So the two solutions I have suggested here to consume web services in Access apply 100% to using drop box.

Comment: On [Box API's](http://developers.box.com/docs/#api-basics), I noticed a Windows API and SDK for developing custom API's. But, my user is more intersted in integrating their Access 2013 app with their customer's case management app, also developed with Access 2007. So is ODBC the best way to go with Access to Access, or is COM still a better choice? I told my user it best to automate box to them, and them to their customer so they dont have to do any manual moving of the content.

Comment: can you join me in a chat? I've been trying to contact you regarding my Pawnshop Mgmt. App.

Comment: Why bother with the web API when all you need/want is the files local on your computer to be processed? VBA has all of the commands to grab + pull files from a local folder. So why not just sync to a local folder and then use plain Jane VBA to process those incoming files with Access.  I am currently using drop box with Access and we are processing 100's of incoming pdf files per day this way. So sync to a local folder and then just use VBA - no web API required. I see little reason to use the web API but using MSXML with Access is likely the best way if you want to use the web API.

Comment: And no, ODBC will not help since drop box has no ODBC connection or internface. So as noted, you need to use "something" that lets you consume web site data - the MSXML library is one such com object if for some reason syncing to a local folder and just using native VBA commands to puck out and process files in that folder will not suffice.

Comment: There's one folder in drop box that receives all the PDF docs for our ~120 customers. Then we manually distribute these docs to ~120 folders on our system, send email notifications to our custs that they new have docs in their folder, they login to us and retrieve the docs from their folder. So how do I automate this using VBA to correctly distribute the docs into the corresponding cust folders on our system? Thesame question applies to forwarding the docs to each cust's Access app.

Comment: If you simply sync and grab the document, or as an alternative use the web service to pull down the document then at that point you have a plan Jane document on your local drive that Access can process. So sync or web service does not "necessary" mean you have  customer information attached to that document. You REALLY better check if the web api gives this information since its not a given. If you don't have customer info attached when you grab that document then no automated routing is possible. You have to adopt separate incoming folders for each customer or use  a file naming convention.